# Crossbars on a dining chair

Tags: wood-repair, safety

We have counter-height dining set. It looks very good and works generally well, but it's difficult to move the chairs in after sitting on them.

So we're considering to convert this back into a regular height dining set.

The table is not an issue - the four legs can be cut down simply.

But we're concerned about the chairs - particularly the fact that the chairs have a couple of cross-bars (one in back, and one in front).

The one is front is lower (currently to let your feet rest on it). But once we reduce the height of the chair, this cross-bar will be about an inch up from the ground - this may interfere with leg movement while someone is sitting down.

So we're thinking of also removing this cross-bar.

The question is - will removing the cross-bar make the chair unstable?

Even though there will still be a cross bar in the back of the chair (and there are similar bars on the sides).

Adding a photo as suggested by others:

[image]

Comment: A picture would really help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. *"The question is - will removing the cross-bar make the chair unstable?"* Less stable, sure, **Un*stable, unknowable. Going by what we've been told my gut says these will be OK if you remove them but there's no way at all to make this judgement properly sight-unseen. TBH I'd be inclined to leave them, ~1"/25mm from the ground doesn't seem like a dealbreaker to me. This sort of modification is a tricky problem because of the limited scope for testing it out. With the remaining crossbars on 3 sides, and assuming all joints are tight, you may not be able to [contd]

Comment: ...remove the front one temporarily to judge as there won't be enough flex/wiggle room in the system. So you would need to commit, remove one destructively to assess whether the chair is rendered too unstable (which only you will be in a position to judge with any certainty). And if it is, then you're stuck unfortunately because you can't then re-install it, or replace with one higher up (as there's even less flex the further up the legs you go) unless you take them entire leg assembly apart, which is not at all easy with solid glue joints (may even be impossible without incurring damage).

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  Unfortunately, there is no way to answer this without pictures and even then, it may be difficult.  One thing that your pictures make clear should be how the legs attach to the seat since removing the cross braces will put additional stress on that connection.

Comment: Thank You - added a photo, hopefully this will help clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks for the added photo, but as @Ashlar said we could have done with a photo that made clear how the legs attach to the seat. However without it my judgement is that, assuming tight joints throughout, removing the front brace shouldn't result in the leg assemblies becoming unstable. However, there is another possible source of instability that would concern me — don't know if others will see it the same way but to me it looks like removing length from the legs could result in unbalancing the chairs, making them prone to tipping back (due to most of the splay on the rear legs being removed).

Comment: Just my opinion (without seeing construction details): if a mass produced chair originally had crossbars/ stretchers to hold the legs together, then it needs those to hold the legs together. (Whether you try and move them around for aesthetics is another question. I wouldn’t. But I wouldn’t cut the legs down in the first place — I’d trade these for the chairs I want.)

Comment: Without the front cross bar there, moving the chair sideways will tend to pull one leg out, putting stress on the leg/seat joint until it fails. I'd follow @AloysiusDefenestrate's advice and simply buy new chairs of the desired height. You can see these to help offset the cost.

Comment: Thank You All for your valuable advice! Much appreciated.